# Progressive Web App app-level scrolling behavior on IPhone / Safari is displaying theme background

Tags: css, iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to get rid of the annoying app-level scrolling behavior for my Progressive Web App when launched from the iPhone's home screen.  When the user pushes up or pulls down on the app, the background theme color of the PWA is revealed. Of course I want a more "app-like" feel where it doesn't do that.  This seems to only happen on Safari on the iPhone - Chrome on Android doesn't behave that way.  The relevant CSS I have tried is below.
In the web manifest I have tried "display": "standalone" and "display": "fullscreen". I made a 13 second YouTube video of the issue here: https://youtube.com/shorts/6uP7VxZ1mdE

[image]

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
    overscroll-behavior-x: contain;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, River, can you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why not `overscroll-behavior: none;`?

Answer (score 2):

**Just share my understanding here:**

Let's first find out what this behaviour is called.

Safari on iOS is written by WKWebView(Chrome also uses it, at least for now), and WKWebView has this property: `underPageBackgroundColor`. See the documentation link: [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3850574-underpagebackgroundcolor). It will try to set the background color of the scroll view to the color of your html body element.

> The web view derives the default value of this property from the
> content of the page, using the background colors of the `<html>` and
> `<body>` elements with the background color of the web view. To override
> the default color, set this property to a new color.

So compare Safari and other browsers' designs: Safari does not have an address bar on the top, and it uses the color of the page to fill the safe area on the top, while Chrome does not have this problem. It has a fixed address bar on the top.
[image]

**If we implement our own WebView in our own app, we can override it to any color we want. But to remove it in Safari, there is no way unless you set the body's background color to transparent.**